# How to set fields (widgets) to readonly in hook_form_alter

Tags: forms

Some fields of my nodes get regularly updated by an external datasource and therefore should not be edited by editors in Drupal. But for UX reasons I still need those fields visible on the edit form.

For input fields I've added the HTML `readonly` attribute, which works quite well:

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();

  if ($form_id == 'node_MYBUNDLE_form' || $form_id == 'node_MYBUNDLE_edit_form') {
    if ($node->hasField('remote_id') && $node->hasField('remote_datasource')) {
      if ($node->get('remote_id')->value && $node->hasField('remote_datasource') == 'SET_BY_MY_IMPORTER') {
        $readonlyFields = ['title', 'body', 'field_image', 'remote_id', 'field_minprice', 'field_roomsize', 'field_minoccupancy', 'field_stdoccupancy', 'field_maxoccupancy', 'field_roomamenity'];
        foreach ($readonlyFields as $rof) {
          $form[$rof]['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
          $form[$rof]['widget'][0]['value']['#description'] = t('This is a readonly import field');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I've got problems with those fields with the "advanced" (non HTML `<input type="text|number|...">`) widgets:

- body is a text field with CKeditor
- field_image is an ER field with Entity browser widget for media entities
- field_roomamenity is an ER field with autocomplete widget for taxonomy terms

Can anybody give me a hint how to set those widgets programmatically to readonly?

Sidenote:
I know there is a [Read-only Field Widget module](https://www.drupal.org/project/readonly_field_widget). But I don't want to change the widget type, because editors can create their own items, which are not served by an external datasource (hence fields `remote_XXX`). In those cases the editors need those widgets in "write mode".

Comment: I think you need to replace those widgets by item elements rather than try to tweak their attributes. But you'll have to work out how to get the default value for the item depending on the field type.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Is it possible to dynamically change the field widget? I've found this [D7 post using hook_field_widget_properties_alter](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2014-10-04/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change), but this hook does not exist in D8's field.api.php

Comment: Unless I am mistaken you can simply replace the whole array for the field for one with #type of 'item'.  You don't need to get clever with the widget as you are making the field read-only. I am sure there will be complications but I don't think this aspect is one of them.

Comment: @Hudri - So did you happen to find a solution to your problem? I am trying to do something similar. Instead of hiding the fields to which the user does not have view/edit permission, I want to make those fields read for that user. Was wondering if I could piggy back on your solution. Thanks!

Comment: @deepkataria Sry, not really, I'm still mostly using `hook_form_alter` for readonly purposes. In some cases I've created my own custom form modes, but only to hide multiple fields/create simplified edit forms.

Comment: @Hudri - No problem! Thanks for the response! :)